# Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext. This stopped SparkContext was created at

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a Pyspark job on AWS EMR. At the very first spark command where I'm trying to read a JSON file from S3 bucket, I get

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
This stopped SparkContext was created at:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("JSON_TO_PARQUET")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('ERROR')

....
....

def main():

            source_json = 's3://' + source_bucket + '/' + source_folder
            df = spark.read.json(source_json)
```

I get this error when it executes the spark.read.json command

Do you have any ideas what could be wrong either with my EMR (1 master/ 1 node) cluster or the above code?

Comment: how big your json file & is your cluster running ?

Comment: json file is decent size and the cluster is definitely running but I found the the problem. Accidently my `spark.stop()` at the end of the code got re-indented out in the way that it was getting executed as soon as the execution starts.I re-indented it properly to align with my code and it solved the problem. :)

Comment: thank you @Srinivas